# how to create slack incoming webhook using the api

Tags: webhooks, slack-api

Is there a way to create the webhooks using an api. I want to automate a group creation and would help having a webhook creation api. But i cant find any doc on how to do this.

Thanks
Suppandi

Comment: curious...why was the question downvoted? am i missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slack does not currently have an API to programmatically create webhooks, thought it is something we're planning on doing in the future. Until then, manually creating them is the recommended approach: https://my.slack.com/services/new

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled on this while searching myself and now slack has api for [generating incoming webhooks programmatically](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks#posting_with_webhooks)